# Javascript.innerHTML is commenting out everything that starts with <?

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know how can I avoid this text from being commented out when using .innerHTML to display results?

```
document.getElementById("Final-Result").innerHTML = "This text will appear, <? while this will be commented out ?>";
```

You can try it out here http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_comments1

**Edit:**
I need the PHP tags to be there, not for functionality reasons but rather displaying an HTML `<code>` block with the code snippet, problem is, if I replaced < and > with `&lt;` and `&gt;` - the whole HTML block will be represented as text.
The other approach is to use RegExp to replace (all) `<?` and `?>` occurrences
What would such a RegExp be like?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, replace < with &lt; and > with &gt;

Comment: From your edit, it seems like you need to construct your DOM in stages, then append it in one go.  Or be able to at least encode just the part that contains the code before appending that to the rest of your HTML snippet you want to assign to `innerHTML`

Comment: @JamesThorpe yeah, encoding only the part that contains the code is way more simple to implement.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you need to encode < > else its trying to parse it as htmltags.

```
&lt; =  < 
&gt; =  >
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

In your case this will be written as

```
document.getElementById("Final-Result").innerHTML = "This text will appear, &lt;? while this will be commented out ?&gt;";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerText` or `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, since it's not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just remove the php tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="myH"></h1>
<p id="myP"></p>

<script>
// Change heading:
document.getElementById("myH").innerHTML = "My First Page";
// Change paragraph:
document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML = "This text will appear, < while this will be commented out >";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with php as PHP is server side and Javascript is client-side.

Answer (score 0):

`<?` and `?>` are shorthand for PHP tags. Why do you want them in an HTML string? Try to wrap them in quotes.

Comment: This makes no difference as PHP is server side and Javascript is client side. Once Javascript starts executing `<?` and `?>` mean nothing anymore.